# Getting and parsing the Spotify Web API JSON with PHP

Tags: php, spotify

My aim is getting the album and its cover image with a given string like "Artist Name - Song Name". For that, I use Spotify Web API and I guess it doesn't require OAuth for these kinds of requests.

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=".$query."&type=track");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$data=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

If you click [the following link](https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=bastille%20-%20pompeii&type=track), you can get the JSON but this request returns me an error page. I've tried with Ajax as well but nothing changed. Can somebody help me about that?

Comment: 400 Bad request

Your browser sent an invalid request. 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `urlencode()` your query before sending it to Spotify, otherwise you will get a `400 Bad Request` response.